# Is there a word for mistakenly using the same equality/information twice?

Tags: terminology

Just wondering if there is a word for using the same equality/information multiple times in for example a proof. Why I'm asking is since I was correcting a proof by a friend and noticed they used the same equality twice, which made the proof insufficient. Then I just started wondering if there is a word for this kinda regular phenomea, does anyone know a good word/phrase for it?

Example:

Prove:
x=z

Proof:
Since x=y we have...

...Long proof...

Now using x=y we have that

...

I understand that this may not always be a mistake, but often it is. Just wondering if there is a good word/phrase for it.

Comment: To re-iterate an [Assumption](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Assumption#Proof_Rule) is not a mistake.

Comment: Perhaps you mean [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) ?

Comment: @user619894 - "begging the question" means to assume the conclusion as a premise of the argument aimed at proving it.

Comment: It is a tricky one, may not be any good word for it, ended up using "contradicting equality usage" in the text. But don't belive that fully describes the error either. Oh well, would just be mostly fun if there would exist som termonology for it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree, but as you have pointed out, OP's question as it stands  is not a mistake, so I thought they might mean something else.

Comment: Did you mean "inefficient", rather than "insufficient"?

Comment: Well no, the proof managed to conclude the sought for relation but so it was not "inefficent" but I belived that this was a cause for error.